adding httpOnly token to axios instance in a nextjs app router project
I used the api router to create a token inside an httpOnly cookie. the problem is the axios instance i created cannot access the cookie.
So i expect the axios instance to get the token to be used as default for all my api calls but if I use this code:
'use server'

import { cookies } from 'next/headers'

import type { AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig } from 'axios'
import axios from 'axios'

import { getBaseUrl } from '../getBaseUrl'

export interface CustomAxiosRequestConfig extends AxiosRequestConfig {
  contentType?: string
}

// Create an Axios instance
export const axiosWithAuth: AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  baseURL: getBaseUrl(),
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Token ${cookies().get('token')?.value}`
  }
})

export const axiosNoAuth: AxiosInstance = axios.create({ withCredentials: true, baseURL: getBaseUrl() })

axiosWithAuth.interceptors.request.use(
  config => {
    const customConfig = config as CustomAxiosRequestConfig

    if (customConfig.contentType) {
      customConfig.headers = {
        ...customConfig.headers,
        'Content-Type': customConfig.contentType
      }
    }

    return config
  },
  error => Promise.reject(error)
)


I get the error that says
Error: cookies was called outside a request scope. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-dynamic-api-wrong-context
so how can i get the cookie and insert it inside the instance?
